# Named views with children in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

I have a single page with multiple `<router-view/>` shown at the same time using [named views](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html).

That works well, however I need to also add children to each view but can't figure out how to do that.

Here is more details on my layout.

The vue main component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <router-view name="files"/>
        <router-view name="forms"/>
        <router-view name="tools"/>
    </div>
</template>
...
```

Router:

```
let router = new Router({
                path: ':resourceTab',
                name: 'Resources',
                components: {
                    files: FilesMain,
                    forms: FormsList,
                    tools: ToolsList,
                },
                props: true,
            })

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router: router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
})
```

Here is what I'm looking to accomplish:

```
           {
                path: ':resourceTab',
                name: 'Resources',
                components: {
                    files: {component: FilesMain, children: [{path: file/:fileId}] <- Just made up this syntax to show the idea. How to accomplish something like this?
                    forms: FormsList,
                    tools: ToolsList,
                },
                props: true,
            }
```

At the moment I do it by adding more paths like below, but that just creates redundancy and I have to pass the value for the "resourceTab" everytime:

```
       {
            path: 'files',
            name: 'Resources',
            components: {files: FilesMain},
            children:[{path: file/:fileId}]
            props () => {resourceTab: "files"},
        },
       {
            path: 'forms',
            name: 'Resources',
            components: {forms: FormsList},
            children:[{path: forms/:formId}]
            props () => {resourceTab: "forms"},
        }

        ...etc
```

Is there a better way of organising subviews in such a dynamic layout?

Comment: Did you find a good solution to this problem?

Comment: @SOK, nope unfortunately. However I've realised that this approach doesn't scale very well and I gave up on that. I needed it mainly for tabs so now I have a TabLayout and I pass components as part of the tabs and instantiate them in code with <component :is="{passComponentHere}"> if that helps